# Overriding server-side validation rule from positive number to number in admin page

Tags: overrides, catalog-price-rules, validation

I am trying to change a validation rule from positive number to any number (so it allows negative numbers too) for the following field:

`[Admin Area] -> Promotions -> Catalogue Price Rules -> Add New Rule -> Actions -> Discount Amount`

I have successfully changed the client-side validation rule but am struggling with the server-side validation rule.

Here's where I have got to:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/CatalogController.php`

`Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_CatalogController::saveAction`

That function seems to fetch a `rule_id` from `$_GET` or `$_POST` and sends it to a `load()` method on the `catalog/rule` model, and then `validateData()` is called on that model with the data from `$_POST`.

I have searched all files for `discount_amount` but didn't seem to find any validation rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it.

`app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php`

`Mage_Rule_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave`

Override that file to the local folder and comment out the first bit of code in that method.